# Android: Notifications, PendingIntent, and actions

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver

I have a question related to creating notifications in Android with an attached action.  My goal is to have an action that won't re-open my app but will simply perform some logic as specified by a class in my app.  Here is my code to create said notification.

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)     context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, RetryReceiver.class);
final PendingIntent retryIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, notificationId, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

final NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder = new   NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
.setContentTitle(title)
.setTicker(ticker)
.setContentText(message)
.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notifcation_sprout_leaf)
.setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
.setAutoCancel(true);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) { 
    mNotifyBuilder.addAction(R.drawable.refresh_action_bar, "Retry", retryIntent);
}

// Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
Intent mainIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

// The TaskStackBuilder needs multiple intents in case there are multiple failures in succession
// Thus default it to have a MainActivity intent it can fall back on
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(mainIntent);
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(composeIntent);

PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(notificationId, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
mNotifyBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

// Because the ID remains unchanged, the existing notification is updated.
notificationManager.notify(notificationId, mNotifyBuilder.build());
```

Here is my class to receive the broadcast:

```
public class RetryReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            // do shit
     }
}
```

I have also registered the receiver in the AndroidManifest.xml as such:

```
<receiver 
    android:name=".RetryReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true" >
</receiver>
```

For some reason, the code in my receiver is never being fired, anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Is RetryReceiver class a file java or a inner class?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your code, if, of course, it is running on a device where `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN`

Comment: I am running it on a Google Nexus 7 tablet running 4.4.2

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `setContentIntent(retryIntent)` on your `mNotifyBuilder` - it is not set automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Attribute `android:exported="true"` is to alow the broadcast receiver receive messages from sources outside its application.

The absence of any filters means that it can be invoked only by Intent objects that specify its exact class name. This implies that the receiver is intended **only for application internal use**.

So `android:exported` should be declared as `android:exported="false"` or not declared because it defaults to false in that case.

As I can't see no other problem with your code. Please try with `android:exported="false"`

See [Receiver Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html)

Comment: Thanks for the input, I got it to work, turns out my device was faulty.

Comment: Could you describe what exactly was wrong in your case? Others might be redirected to this question with the same issue.